# How to create new website in IIS using Web Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, iis, web-setup-project, vs-web-application-project

I have a Web Application Project and a Web Setup Project in my Solution.

When I run the MSI created by the Web Setup Project it only gives me the option to use an already existing website in the IIS on the local machine.

How can I get the installer to give me the option to create a new website in IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it with the tools as provided...

BUT you can add custom installer actions that will run pretty much any code you like (see this [MSDN installer article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(VS.80).aspx)) from there all you need is some code to create the site as you want it... that you should be able to lookup on google.